# Searching for un-used media in Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco

I'm very new to using Umbraco, but I am looking for a way to sort the media files so I can see which files haven't been linked to any content yet? e.g. PDFs that are yet to be put onto any page.

Is there a simple way of doing this? Or can someone talk me through step-by-step what to do?

Thanks,
Becky

Comment: How firm are you with C#? Maybe you could use the Umbraco Services to write you own controller (e.g. surface controller) to get a list of not linked files. See https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management/Services/

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extension like https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/falm-housekeeping/ to clean out all the unused media.

When working with extensions I would make a copy of your project and test it out on there first as some extensions can be quite temperamental.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but I don't necessarily want to delete the unused items, is there a way just to generate a list of them or something of the sort?

Comment: I've not used the plugin myself but there is a possibility it will show you the 'orphaned' media files before asking you to delete them. The screenshot shows a 'show orphaned files to delete' button.There might be a fancy way SQL query you can run on the database to find these media files but I am not too sure where I would begin with that.